# How Do I ensure that my MSI project is built into a package that is compatible with a specific msiexec version?

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I have a windows installer (MSI) project. I want to ensure that when i build it , it will be compatible with msiexec version 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, compatibility is a problem with a lower verions. Windows Installer 4.5 is the latest version of windows installer and I would expect it to be backward compatible. So, most likely things that you are using will be supported.

What you should worry about is compatibility with older versions of Windows Installer. Most IDEs for creating installers would let you know if you are using something that is available only after some version of Windows Installer onwards.

If your IDE does not provide this feature then you should be aware of what all you are using in your MSI and make sure thats its available in the Windows Installer version you intend to you target with your installer.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the tool you use to build the MSI, you should be able to specify the required installer version there.

For example, [WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), which I frequently use has a "InstallerVersion" attribute at its ["Package" XML Element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_package.htm). There I can specify which Windows Installer Version is required.

(Currently I do not require Installer 4.5 as it isn't deployed everywhere yet and I don't want to require customers to install the new installer on XP.)

**Update:**

Re-reading your question I get the impression that you use a Visual Studio Installer project. I believe you can't configure the Windows Installer Version there, but it defaults to Windows Installer 3.whatever (I'm not sure about the specific minor version). Setups created with that are compatible with Windows XP in any way.

I don't believe you WANT to require a newer version of Windows Installer when you use a Visual Studio setup project, as the setup project is very limited in what it can do. So to require a newer version of the installer you probably have a specific feature in mind (for example elevation on Vista). To use that feature you'd need a better tool to build installers anyways (like WIX, or Installshield or Wise or ...)

Comment: Yes I am using VS2008 ,Assuming it defaults to version 3,  All i need to know is whether msiexec 4.5 will run my MSI package with all the options (by saying all , I mean ***ALL*** the options that msiexec can give , This is an important requirement in my project). Can you please post me back an answwer , thanks!

Comment: As I said earlier, msiexec 4.5 *should* be backward compatible. You can create the msi and test it on Windows Installer 4.5 if you want to.